# Good way to extract a subset of key-value pairs from a dictionary, based on a value in a key value pair

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a table represented in a Dictionary, where each key corresponds to the column name, and the (value) List holds the values for that column's rows. So the index of the list items is my row index.

Trying to figure out a linq C# implementation that would give me the indices of a value in a column, and thereby derive its adjacent column values for the other keys. For example, if my table representation looks like so:

```
    Key1  AA   BB   JX   TR FT
    Key2  AX   BC   SF   XO ST
    Key3  22   22   22   21 21
    Key4  AW   BM   ND   NC PO
    Key5  AZ   BN   SD   DS ZX
```

I'd like to find the value with most occurrences in Key3, say 22, and extract a subset of key-value pairs for just adjacent values for Key1 and Key2. I've seen examples of how to get indices of duplicates, and from that I could derive the subset dictionary by iterating, but ideally I'd like it to be one statement that does it.

Currently using from an example from this forum for the criteria: number

```
    var result = Enumerable.Range(0, table["Key3"].Count)
                     .Where(i => table["Key3"][i] == number)
                     .ToList();
```

Hoping someone can suggest a way to add the extraction of the subset dictionary to this statement.

Comment: what are " adjacent values " in a dictionary? a dictionary inherently has no defined ordering, other than coincidence

Comment: What may be the expected output?

Comment: For example, the adjacent value for the first occurrence of 22, would be the corresponding value (via index 0) in key2 and key1. I realize there's no ordering in a dictionary, but surely the List does preserve the order in which items were added. Hope that clarifies.

The final expected output is a subset dictionary of Key1, Key2, Key3 containing values via Dict[key].ElementAt(index) - index being 0, 1, 2 given the occurrences of 22.

Comment: `Key1` and `Key2` does not contain value: `22`. But if you want to return an index of `22` for `Key3`, you can use simple trick.

Comment: That's what I'm after. For every matching value based on my criteria, on Key3, I want it's corresponding Key1 and Key2 values. I can use the index to get to them, but I'm hoping there a simpler way than that.

Comment: If i understand you well, you want to return: `{Key 1 {ElementAt(0), ElementAt(1), AlementAt(2)}, Key 2 {ElementAt(0), ElementAt(1), AlementAt(2)}, Key 3 {ElementAt(0), ElementAt(1), AlementAt(2)}}`. Am i right? Why you do not want to return corresponding values for `Key4` and `Key5`?

Comment: It's not needed, but if we can get all keys for the corresponding match, that would still be better than traversing the entire dictionary.

Comment: I'm not getting you... Can you improve your question by adding expected result?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, i'm not sure i understand well what you want to achieve...

Second of all, as [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) mentioned in the comment to the question, `Dictionary` object has no defined ordering and indexes, unless it is [OrderedDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary(v=vs.100).aspx).

Third of all, the best option in your case is to use `for` loop, because this is always(*) faster then any Linq solution.

*-usually ;)

My best guess is:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> oDict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

oDict.Add("Key1", new List<string>{"AA", "BB", "JX", "TR", "FT"});
oDict.Add("Key2", new List<string>{"AX", "BC", "SF", "XO", "ST"});
oDict.Add("Key3", new List<string>{"22", "22", "22", "21", "21"});
oDict.Add("Key4", new List<string>{"AW", "BM", "ND", "NC", "PO"});
oDict.Add("Key5", new List<string>{"AZ", "BN", "SD", "DS", "ZX"}); 
//key to find
string searchedKey = "Key3";
//value to find
string searchedValue = "22";
//get index of Key
var keyIndex = oDict.Keys.ToList().IndexOf(searchedKey);  //if not found, returns -1
//returns 2

//get the list of indexes where the value has been found
var valIndexes = Enumerable.Range(0, oDict[searchedKey].Count)
             .Where(i => oDict[searchedKey][i] == searchedValue)
             .ToList();
//returns: {0, 1, 2}

//get distination resultset
var resultSubset = oDict
                    .Take(keyIndex+1) //take the no. of Keys
                    .ToDictionary(a=>a.Key,
                            a=>a.Value.Where((x,z) => valIndexes
                                                    .Any(i=> i==z)) 
                                                    .Select(x=>x).ToList());
```

Above code returns: `Dictionary<<string>, List<string>>()`:

```
Key1, {AA, BB, JX} 
Key2, {AX, BC, SF} 
Key3, {22, 22, 22}
```

Comment: Thanks Maciej Los. My apologies for the fuzzy description, but you've nailed it exactly the way I wanted to do it.  I haven't tried the code, but I'm pretty sure it works. Yeah, I do understand that a Dictionary object doesn't have a notion of ordering. In fact I'm actually relying here on the ordering based on the addition to the List<string> which is the value in the dictionary. Thanks again.